# Django: comment_create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk' error

Tags: django

I am now implementing a comment function on the post_detail page.
but occurred comment_create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk' error.

I also tried to change the def comment_creat(request, post_pk): part to def comment_creat(request, pk): on views.py.

and I try {% url 'comment_create' pk=post.pk %} --> post_pk=post.pk

views.py

```
@login_required
def comment_create(request, post_pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_pk)
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        com_user = request.user

        if not content:
            messages.info(request, 'Write please')
            return redirect('post_detail', post_pk)
    Comment.objects.create(post=post, comment_user=com_user, comment_content=content)
    return redirect('post_detatil', post_pk)
```

urls.py

```
path('post_detail/<int:pk>/comment_create/',views.comment_create, name='comment_create')
```

post_detail.html

```
<form action="{% url 'comment_create' pk=post.pk %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text", name="content", placeholder="comment...">
    <input type="submit", value="Go">
</form>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

In your view, the name of the argument is `post_pk`:

```
@login_required
def comment_create(request, post_pk):
    # ...
```

but in your URL patterns, you use just `pk`:

```
path('post_detail/<int:pk>/comment_create/',views.comment_create, name='comment_create')
```

You can rename any of the two, but renaming the parameter in the `urls.py`, will result in updating all `{% url ... %}`s for that view as well, so it is likely that renaming the parameter in the view, will result in less editing:

```
@login_required
def comment_create(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        com_user = request.user

        if not content:
            messages.info(request, 'Write please')
            return redirect('post_detail', pk)
    Comment.objects.create(post=post, comment_user=com_user, comment_content=content)
    return redirect('post_detatil', pk)
```

Note that typically retrieving and validating data is done through a `Form`, not by the view itself.